# MASM syntax for mov [string], WORD PTR 'HE'

Tags: assembly, nasm, masm

I follow this tutorial on assembly:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_addressing_modes.htm
They use NASM. I use MASM.

I have this string:

```
string db 'hello string from asm here'
```

I want to modify the string in the program.
I want to replace the first 2 letters.

```
mov [name],  dword 'Nuha'
```

So i try:

```
mov [string], WORD 'HE'
```

Which trows error a2070.
It can do this:

```
mov [string], 'H'
```

Output: Hello string from asm here
Then i found this:

```
mov word ptr [string], 'HE'
```

it compiles, but reads it from the back to the front
Output: EHllo string from asm here
I want: HEllo string from asm here

So how do i move a word value into a string in MASM?

PS. Does anyone have a better source, tutorial for MASM and not NASM?

Thanks in advance,

Cody

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HE` as a word is worth `'0x4845'`. When you put it in memory, it is serialized as little endian (since you're using an intel x86 or x64 processor) => Bytes are swapped: hex dump: `0x45 0x48`

You have the behaviour you're expecting if you do:

```
 mov [string] WORD PTR, 'EH'
```

(you could have figured out yourself but now you know the reason)

I checked `NASM` documentation and they do a special thing with strings, probably because it is more convenient:

```
  dw    0x1234              ; 0x34 0x12 
  dw    'a'                 ; 0x61 0x00 (it's just a number) 
  dw    'ab'                ; 0x61 0x62 (character constant) 
  dw    'abc'               ; 0x61 0x62 0x63 0x00 (string)
```

note that `dw` "swaps" strings word/longs but not hex values.

MASM is more "basic" and this swap is not done, which explains the "standard" behaviour you're experiencing.

Note: it's a kind of a hack to do it that way. Calling a byte-to-byte copy routine is better and more generic. Porting such a code from MASM to NASM (or the other way round) could have catastrophic results.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I get that it will use little endian, but why doesnt the example in the tutorial? Also i made a mistake, the line that compiles goes; MOV WORD PTR [string], 'HE'; Sorry for that.

Comment: see my edit. NASM has special swap method for strings.